# Methods for computing signature

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Define signature of a real-coefficient polynomial with only real roots, as difference of number of its positive real roots and negative real roots. One method for computing signature of a polynomial is to compute its roots, another one is considering number of sign changes in its coefficients. Is there any other methods except these which doesn't require computing roots themselves?

Answer (score 0):

There is [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) that gives a algorithm to compute the number of real roots in any given half open interval $(a,b]$. While it is still in a sense a method that count sign changes, the difference is that in this theorem you know exactly where to check if the sign has changed (and not worry if two roots are very close to each other and you might have missed the segment between them).